# Incorrect answer deleted by a ♦ moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, wrong-answers

I recently came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435651/check-if-worksheet-in-workbook-has-specific-name-and-change-it-if-it-does/55435715#55435715) answer in review. The answer is fine and is a valid attempt to answer the question. I see no reason for it to be deleted, but it was deleted by a moderator with a comment explaining that it was incorrect. Incorrect answers should be downvoted, not deleted, but in this case it was deleted, not downvoted.

Here's a screenshot of the answer:

[image]

Should this answer be deleted or not?

Comment: This answer isn't wrong. It's on the wrong question.

Comment: @Braiam it seemed like the answerer was on the question they intended to answer. It mentions catching specific errors on worksheets with one of two names. That's *exactly* what the question talks about.

Comment: The phrase "The road to hell is paved with good intentions" isn't just a cool sounding one. Intentions don't matter. What matter is the actions and their result. The question was asking for something, and the answerer misguidedly tried to be helpful by providing an "answer". Just that it failed to answer the question.

Comment: @Braiam that's what I'm saying: the poster attempted to answer the question, but the solution was incorrect. [That's exactly what downvoting is for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). The [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) where you get to vote to delete answers says nothing about deleting wrong answers; it only says extremely low quality answers or non-answers should be deleted.

Comment: Ask yourself this: does the answer make Stack Overflow (and, by extension, the Internet) even the slightest bit better?

Comment: Attempt isn't enough. That's what I'm saying. They should address the points on the question.

Answer (score 16):

**I deleted the answer because it was *irrelevant* to the question.**

The comment I left there is testament to its irrelevance. I leave comments like that when deleting things in part so that post-mortem questions like this one can be avoided. I see that it did not work. Sigh, oh well.

Irrelevant answers get deleted all the time. Their deletion makes the site better. Users with deletion privileges are allowed and even advised to use those privileges in the service of the site, curating content and making the useful information easier to find. The whole point of restricting deletion privileges is to ensure that the users who have them are: (1) familiar with how this site is supposed to operate, and (2) competent in at least one programming-related technology.

I meet both of those criteria. I have "trusted user" privileges, both due to my earned reputation and my status as an elected moderator. I know several different programming languages, including VBA. I know quite well what sort of content we're optimizing for.

As such, I was entirely within my rights to delete that answer, just as any trusted user would be well within their rights to delete that answer. I don't know where you got the impression that moderators are somehow forbidden from deleting answers except under certain circumstances. That's not at all true. If you're uncomfortable with the fact that it was deleted by a moderator, consider that it was deleted by a trusted user who is an expert in the relevant technology. I didn't stop being a trusted community member when I became a moderator. If anything, the level of trust *increased*.

**You keep saying that "the solution was incorrect", but that's a misrepresentation. The purported solution was *irrelevant* to the question that was asked, because it recommended using constructs that do not exist in the language under discussion.**

> Q: Is there an API to automatically hide the taskbar on Windows?
>
> A: You should use `AutoHideDock()`, which automatically hides the Dock on macOS.

Yes, I made up that API. I have no idea if macOS has such an API. That's because I am a Windows programmer, and it's for that same reason that such an answer would be completely irrelevant and useless to a question asking about Windows programming. Such answers *can* be, and *should* be, deleted because they are unhelpful noise. This is the whole reason the site gives users deletion privileges.

You are perhaps getting confused with the guidance you've read on Meta regarding *flags*. The recommendation is that you not flag answers as "not an answer" or "very low quality" because of technical concerns. The purpose of this advice is highly practical. There is no guarantee that the moderator who processes your flags is going to be an expert in the relevant technology, so when you raise flags like this on technical grounds, you risk having those flags declined because those moderator simply cannot judge whether or not the answer is applicable.

The *purpose* of those flags is not to handle incorrect content, or that which can be objected to on technical grounds, but rather to delete *obvious* garbage. If it's *obvious* why the answer is irrelevant or inapplicable, then it's fine to flag it as NAA or VLQ. For example, a PHP answer to a C++ question, or an answer recommending the use of non-existent language constructs. If it's less obvious, it might be useful to use a custom flag to explain the problem(s) to a moderator, or to ask a group of trusted users who are subject-matter experts to use their delete votes. You could also just take your chances with a NAA or VLQ flag. That's all up to you. It doesn't constrain the actions of the moderators. If the moderator who handles the flag *is* a subject matter expert, or if a moderator happens to come across the answer in the normal course of their using the site, there's nothing wrong with them using that knowledge to make the site a better place.

There's only one possible concern with an answer like this being deleted by a moderator, and that's the potential for it to used as an audit. I agree that such an audit could potentially trip up a well-meaning reviewer who was unfamiliar with VBA. Of course, the situation would best be addressed by the reviewer using "Skip" (**which is what *you* should have done, by the way, when you reviewed this answer in the Low Quality Posts queue**). But, in this case, I also took steps to ensure that this deleted answer would *not* be an audit candidate.

Comment: Just a couple of things I'd like to point out: 1) the main point in all this is not that it was deleted by a moderator, just that it was deleted. I'm not claiming you don't have the "rights" to delete the answer, 2) when reviewing the answer, I saw no unfixable problems whatsoever with it. I felt I understood it well enough to review it, 3) I disagree with your reasoning. While the answer may have been wrong, I believe you should have downvoted so it would show up below other answers. Deletion really doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: *"I felt I understood it well enough to review it"* You obviously didn't, and still don't. @pik

Comment: Read my last point in my previous comment. I do not think it should have been deleted as it was absolutely a valid attempt to answer the question. Even though it may have been wrong, it should not be deleted. I edited to make it into an answer. It was still an incorrect answer, yes, but it was an answer nonetheless. I'm not going to delete valid attempts to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard - trolling OP with answers that are clearly over their head or subtly (or completely) invalid is entertaining for some authors, but I really don't see it as even remotely nice (and definitely not aligned with site's goals). Do you for example also upvote spam answers (as authors put some effort for "valid attempt" too)?